# Makefile string variable

Tags: variables, makefile

I need to create a variable with spaces in my Makefile:

```
CC=$(LFS_TGT)-gcc -B$(TOOLS)/release/lib/
```

What is a right way to do that?

**UPDATE:**
 My code does not work, I have an error, something like bash cannot find command -B$(TOOLS)/release/lib/.

Comment: Do you mean your variable name should contain spaces or that the variable should contain a value which includes spaces?

Comment: The value should contain spaces.

Comment: Your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 9):

If I've guessed correctly as to what you mean, including extra quoting in the variable definition should work, i.e.:

```
TOOLS = 'dir with spaces'
CC    = $(LFS_TGT)-gcc -B$(TOOLS)/release/lib/
```